# killing zombie children in parent processes

Tags: php, mysql, pear, pcntl

So I want to do the following:
Set up a daemon that forks a bunch of processes.

So the Daemon forks a bunch of processes
then forks another bunch of processes

the problem is the child processes might take a long time to exit. How do I prevent zombie children if the parent process has other work to do despite forking children?

The parent process (the daemon) does something like this:

```
while(true)
{
SQL QUERY EXECUTED

   while(mysql_fetch_array)
   {
       Fork children
   }
}
```

The problem is how can I wait for the children processes to exit if the parent process has to do other work besides forking children and if the children take a long time to exit.

I am using the System daemon PEAR function to create the daemon and the `pcntl_fork` function to create the processes.

Comment: I viewed this question because of the title. Just sayin'

Comment: And the question itself didn't disappoint: "I want to set up a daemon that forks a bunch of processes." Wasn't that a Roman Polanski film?

Comment: @Problematic, the UNIX terminology about processes is quite macabre. I mean, the daemon parent should really do its best efforts to kill its children in order to prevent them from becoming zombies. You really don't want zombies running around the system just because the parent failed to kill its own children...

Comment: nothing a good shotgun cant help with :P

Comment: You can do it with fire.

Comment: Should add a `doubleTap()` function to your daemon, don't want those zombies getting back up.

Comment: @PontaOnasys It's a joke. We're all terrible people giggling over killing zombie children.

Comment: @BenBrocka: My proposal can actually be called `doubleFork()` and takes care of zombies :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't remember where I saw this:

```
Parent forks child
  Waits until child is dead  (this won't take long, see ahead)
  Goes on

Child does only 2 things:
  Forks a grandchild
  Exits

Grandchild does whatever work is needed
  Exits
```

The trick is that when the Granchild dies, its parent (one of your Children) is already dead. But someone has to be notified for the death. It appears that in Linux systems, it's not the grandparent that is notified but the grand-grand-...-grandparent of all. And because that process knows its job, it periodically checks for dead children and does not allow them to become zombies.

Here's a link with explanation: http://fixunix.com/unix/533215-how-avoid-zombie-processes.html

> When a process's parent terminates, the "init" process takes over as its
>   parent. So when the child process exits, the grandchild loses its
>   parent, and is **adopted** by init. Init **always reaps its dead children**, so
>   they don't become zombies.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider having the parent do nothing other than wait for the children. If the parent dies for any reason, then the children will become zombies. If the parent however doesn't *do* anything, then there are very few chances for it to die unexpectedly.

Comment: the problem is that I am dealing with time sensitive information. The daemon parent process checks the database for an event that is to occur at a specific time, forks child processes to handle the event, and then goes back to check another time to see if there are any other events that are supposed to occur at that time. So you see, the parent process needs to keep working. Is there a more efficient way of accomplishing this?

Comment: @Pota Onasys, why don't you use processes instead of forks?

Comment: @Pota Onasys, that should work. You wouldn't need to concern yourself with zombies anymore.

Comment: You always need to concern yourself with zombies.

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly set your `SIGCHLD` handler to `SIG_IGN` (instead of `SIG_DFL`) this will stop your children becoming zombie processes, assuming you're not interested in their exit codes. Alternatively on newer Linuxes you should use `sigaction`'s `SA_NOCLDWAIT` flag instead.